# On S3 Mini, Heimdall ERROR: Partition "RECOVERY" does not exist in the specified PIT

Tags: partitions, heimdall

Following this guide for Samsung S3 Mini to install recovery: http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Install_CM_for_i9300

1. Started up in download mode
2. connected USB
3. in Terminal (Linux user), typed in 
   `heimdall flash --RECOVERY <file-name>.img --no-reboot`

The Terminal returned the error:

```
ERROR: Partition "RECOVERY" does not exist in the specified PIT.
```

What do?

Answer (score 3):

I managed to solve as follows (on Linux):

Cause of problem:
In the PIT, there is no partition, called "RECOVERY" (duh). Keep in mind, the command is case sensitive.

Have a look at the PIT:

```
sudo heimdall print-pit --verbose
```

On my phone the recovery-related partition was called "Kernel2"

What worked is:

```
sudo heimdall flash --Kernel2 recovery-clockwork-6.0.4.6-i9300.img --no-reboot
```

Comment: And does the phone after that worked with the new OS? The S3 mini is a i8190 (not supported) and not a i9300. Please see https://www.reddit.com/r/LineageOS/comments/alpgip/samsung_galaxy_s3_mini_gti8190_handled_like_i9300/